# How to perform segue after clicking anywhere in a section of TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

In my app there is a tableView with five sections. The header title for the 5th section is "Notes" and the text of the cell is "Click here to add notes". After clicking on the cell the app segues to another view controller with a textView. In order to make it more user friendly, I want when users click anywhere below the header title (yellow area in screenshot), the app can segue to the textView. Anyway to do this? My code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.section {

// case 0 - 3

    case 4:

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toTextView", sender: self)

    default: break


    }

}
```

[tableview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXdtg.png)

Comment: Isn't "below the header title" the cell that you are already handling? What exactly are you asking? What issue are you having?

Comment: Hi rmaddy, thanks for answering my question again. I mean now users must click on the cell. If they click somewhere else under the cell,  nothing happens. I don't think that is user friendly. I want users click anywhere under that cell, it will perform the segue. This may sounds weired, but anyway to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "under the cell"? Isn't there another cell there?

Comment: Hi All, there is only one row in section 5 with text "Click to add notes". If click on this cell, it will segue to the textView. But there are rows under this cell in the tableView and I want it to segue to the textView too when clicking on any of them.

Comment: Wouldn't the switch you've provided segue whenever a cell within section 4 is selected? Is this not what you want?

Comment: @ZGski I want more than that. The area of the cell is too small. If users don't know they must click on that cell, and click somewhere else, it won't segue and it is not user friendly.

Comment: If you think the cell is too small you can always make its dimensions bigger to make it clear that you need to click on that cell in order to segue. UI be as simple as possible.

Comment: @ZGski  I added a screenshot. I mean when users click within the yellow area it can perform the segue. Thanks.

Comment: Are all of the cells in yellow part of section 4, or are they in a 5th section?

Comment: "Notes" is header of section 5. There is only one cell at section 5, whose text is "Click here to add notes". Cells in yellow part are not in section 5. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @ZGski  I updated screenshot. Please help to edit again.

Comment: Are the cells in yellow in a 6th section?

Comment: @ZGski Sorry for the late reply. No, there is no 6th section. I updated screenshot again, please help to edit it again.

Comment: So what section are those cells in?

Comment: No more section .........., it is part of the tableview.

Comment: Cells have to be in a section.

Comment: I know this requirement may be not reasonable, do you think it is quite possible users don't click on the cell, but somewhere else?

Comment: If you have cells that exist after section 5, but are not part of section 6, how are you creating them? Do you really need the cells in this limbo section, or could you just end your tableView after section 5?

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` function, you would want to check the selected row's section before performing any code. I've included an example conditional that would be placed inside of your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` method.

```
if indexPath.section == 4 {
    // Perform Your Segue HERE //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean footerView of the tableView? If you want to handle the tap event on the footerView, consider add a tapGestureRecongizer on it.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let tapGestureRecongizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecongizer)
    }

    func handleGesture(gestureRecongnizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toTextView", sender: self)
    }
```